# xunit run same test twoices times

Tags: selenium, asp.net-core, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, xunit.net

I created a solution with XUnit using Net Core 3.1. I just created a test with Selenium.
When running just this test, it is run twice in a row. I can't understand where this behavior comes from.

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using System;
using Xunit;

namespace LabXUnitTest
{
    public class UnitTest1 : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly IWebDriver _driver;
        public UnitTest1()
        {
            _driver = new ChromeDriver();
            _driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _driver.Quit();
        }

        [Fact]
        public void Test1()
        {
            _driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://myUrl/Login");

            var inputUsuario = _driver.FindElement(By.Id("input-usuario"));
            inputUsuario.SendKeys("Dev");

            var inputPassword = _driver.FindElement(By.Id("input-password"));
            inputPassword.SendKeys("dev");

            var btnLogin = _driver.FindElement(By.Id("btn-login"));
            btnLogin.Click();

            Assert.Contains("DashBoard", _driver.Url);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the output of the window when your test explorer is running?

Or you can check the current dependencies. If you find a different version, uninstall an old version and restart VS to retest. If this is not the reason, you can post your test output.

Comment: Correct. In fact there were conflicting versions so it had this behavior. Thanks